# zipWith in Scala using map

Tags: scala, dictionary, zip

Define zipWith. It should zip two lists, but instead of zipping elements into a tuple,
 it should use a function to combine two elements.

Example: zipWith(List(1, 2, 3),
                  List(10, 11, 12),
                  (x: Int, y: Int) => x+y)
 Should return: List(11,13,15)

use map and zip.

```
def zipWith[A,B,C](xs: List[A], ys: List[B], f: (A, B) => C): List[C] = {
        val zs = xs.zip(ys)
        //I don't know how to do this because if myMap(zs, f) 

        //myMap takes a functin f:(a)=>b instead of f: (A, B) => C
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to **map** the zipped list, you can use _pattern matching_ to properly call the function. - `(xs lazyZip ys).map { case (x, y) => f(x, y) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you looking for something like this:

```
def zipWith[A,B,C](xs: List[A], ys: List[B], f: (A, B) => C): List[C] = {
  (xs, ys) match {
    case (Nil, _) => Nil
    case (_, Nil) => Nil
    case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => f(x, y) :: zipWith(xs, ys, f)
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

Here is the same function but being tail-recursive:

```
    def zipWith[A, B, C](xs: List[A], ys: List[B], f: (A, B) => C): List[C] = {
      @tailrec
      def zipAccumulatingResult(xs: List[A], ys: List[B], f: (A, B) => C, acc: List[C]): List[C] = {
        (xs, ys) match {
          case (Nil, _) => acc
          case (_, Nil) => acc
          case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => zipAccumulatingResult(xs, ys, f, acc :+ f(x, y))
        }
      }

      zipAccumulatingResult(xs, ys, f, Nil)
    }
```

Comment: It would be better to provide a _tail-recursive_ solutiuon.

Comment: yes or maybe use the scala map function? but this works thanks!!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, that makes sense, I've updated answer.
Although I found that your answer might be the better fit.